# Checkboxes patently refuse to submit information onclick- HELP

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, checkbox, onclick

Hi this is my second post (and second week programming, ever) so apologies in advance.

I have a list of checkboxes that represent different search filters that I want passed to params.  For example, if this were a restaurant search, I would want my users to be able to check off different types of cuisine that they are interested in.  Just like Yelp.

All I want to do is to send the new parameters each time someone clicks on an option.  I DON'T care about AJAX right now (I'll cross that bridge when I come to it).

Can i do this with an observe_form even though I'm not using AJAX?  Can I use javascript? I've seen stuff about "event handlers" but i have no idea what those are. I hate to give up and ask but i've now been working for 19 hours and I can't handle anymore.  Thanks!

CODE: (UPDATED FOR TYPO)

```
      <div id="cuisine_form_div">
  <% form_tag(hotels_path, :method => "GET", :id => :cuisine_form ) do %> 
  <%= check_box_tag('my_cuisine[]', 'Mexican', :onclick => "document.cuisine_form.submit();" ) %>
  <%= label_tag(:my_cuisine, "Mexican", :onclick => "document.cuisine_form.submit();" ) %>
  <%= check_box_tag('my_cuisine[]', 'Delis') %>
  <%= label_tag(:my_cuisine, "Delis") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'update' %>
  <% end %>
  </div><!--end.id="cuisine_form_div"-->
```

---

Note that whenever I insert the javascript like above, it prechecks the box on the screen but doesn't submit any info to the URL.  If I click the submit button, everything works great, but "onclick"  I can't get the URL to budge.

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking what you're wanting to do is on each click you'll need to test the 'checked' state of the checkbox.  At that point you will need to read in what is checked from the ID or VALUE attribute.  Then you can alert() the value to debug or use console.log if you're using Firebug or Developer tools in Chrome.

Also, you will want to write a function to put in your onClick event instead of trying to write the logic within the event.

start by just creating a function such as

```
function clickCheckbox {
   /* paste your existing onClick logic */
}
```

and modify it from there...

If you need exact syntax let me know.

I recommend using jQuery.  Add the jQuery library to your head tag on all of your pages.  This enables easier to use functions for AJAX and things.

You can do:

```
$('#CheckboxID').click(function() {
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        $(this).attr('checked',false);
    } else {
        $(this).attr('checked',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm sure this is stupid but mind walking me through this?  

1) "test the 'checked' state of the checkbox" - how?  When I look at the checkbox in firebug, the markup looks the same regardless of whether it is checked.
2) "read in what is checked from the ID or VALUE attribute" - 'read' by looking at the mark up?  are "id" and "value" the same?  i thought "id" = "name".  
3) "alert() the value to debug" - you mean changing the JS to :onchange => "alert(this.value);" correct?
4) "write a function..." - your saying to write out a new function that is triggered...how?

lots to learn...thx

Comment: I recommend using jQuery, it helps make a lot of the Javascript syntax easier for AJAX stuff.  Add the jQuery library to your pages.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of errors, but now it is working in my test app! :)

These points were missing/broken

- Form needs `id` in order to find it in Javascript
- [check_box_tag](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#M001737) needs a third parameter to set selected state (and fourth (your third) is to add HTML code)
- Use onchange, so it does not matter whether the user clicks on the checkbox or on the label
- Add correct id to checkbox, so the label is attached to it
- Fix label according to the previous updates/fixes

The resulting form becomes more like this:

```
<% form_tag(cuisine_path, :method => "GET", :id => :cuisine_form, :name => :cuisine_form ) do %>
  <%= check_box_tag('my_cuisine[]', 'Mexican', true, { :id => :cuisine_mexican, :onchange => "document.cuisine_form.submit();" }) %>
  <%= label_tag(:cuisine_mexican, "Mexican" ) %>
  <%= check_box_tag('my_cuisine[]', 'Delis', false, { :id => :cuisine_delis, :onchange => "document.cuisine_form.submit();" }) %>
  <%= label_tag(:cuisine_delis, "Delis") %>
  <%= submit_tag 'update' %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Awesome, that did work!  Can you just clarify a few things for me so I don't make the same mistakes:

1) "form needs id" - check.  "name" doesn't work.
2) "third/fourth parameters" I would like to have the boxes remain checked after the reload.  I've achieved this by extracting parameters and conditional logic but is there an easier way?
3) I get your naming convention, makes sense.  but why do you put the ":id" and the JS together in a hash?

Thanks a bunch!  This community thing is great!

Comment: Good to hear! For 2) I think your solution is basically the only thing you could do since there is no Model behind the form. 3) If you look at the check_tag_box documentation, you can see that the last parameter is an options hash used to generate extra HTML.

Comment: Oh btw since you are new: to support this community you can vote on answers you think are helping you (or are helpful in general). And for your own question you can pick an answer that is the solution for your problem. This way others visitors of a question see which answers they should pick when facing the same problem.